# Install Aircrack-ng on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ubuntu, aircrack-ng

I am trying to install Aircrack-ng.  All of the instructions are working now up until the point of doing the make.  When I issue make I get the following error.

root@ubuntu:~/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1# make 
make -C src all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1/src'
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3  -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude  wpaclean.o osdep/radiotap/radiotap.o -o wpaclean -Losdep -losdep -lnl-genl-3 -lnl-3 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnl-genl-3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:189: recipe for target 'wpaclean' failed
make[1]: *** [wpaclean] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc1/src'
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Anyone have a clue how to fix this error?

Comment: Really.  How is this question off-topic?  I asked a simple question as to how to fix a simple error.  It really doesn't matter now since the training is well past over and I got around the issue, but this really seems like a case of people overstepping their bounds because they have reputation and feel like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried using Aircrack on several Linux distribution and issues like this one happened quite often (usually because of dependency problems).

I solved all problems by installing [Backtrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/), which contains all the packages you need, pre-installed.

You can install it to USB drive as well